# strcpy': unsafe and fprintf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char '

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am updating a program to be used with a current project I am working. I have been able to worked through most of the errors however I have two that have me stuck these keep coming up on build.

the first on is *"'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead."* if I use strcpy_s in the code below I get the following *"no instance of overloaded function strcpy_s"* I also get *" '=': conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'char', possible loss of data"* for the code below

```
    static char * StringToCharArray(String^ val)
{
    char * returnVal = new char[val->Length];
    strcpy(returnVal,"");
    for(int i=0;i<val->Length;i++)
        returnVal[i] = val[i];
    return returnVal;
}
```

my second error is *"'fprintf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'cli::array ^'"*

```
    void onRenamed( Object^ sender, RenamedEventArgs^ e )
   {       
       char dateString[9], timeString[9];
       //These functions (from time.h) retrieve the current date and time
       _strdate_s(dateString); _strtime_s(timeString);
       openFile();
       fprintf(fOutput,"%s Renamed to %s on %s at %s \n",e->OldFullPath->ToCharArray(),e->FullPath->ToCharArray(),dateString,timeString);
       closeFile();
   }
```

Comment: You're apparently using Visual Studio. If so then read [this `strcpy_s` reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=vs-2017) to learn its arguments and how to use it.

Comment: The second error is because you're not programming C++ really, but a Microsoft-specific derivateive called [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI). It's not backward compatible with standard C++, and even less compatible with C (from which [the `std::printf` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) comes from). As `printf` is a C function it knows nothing of C++ object and even less about C++/CLI managed pointers.

Comment: `String` in this case is a C++/CLI unicode string, so it contains `wchar_t` characters, not `char` characters, hence the "conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'char', possible loss of data" warning in the `=` loop. You can't just copy `wchar_t` characters as-is to a `char` buffer, there is indeed a potential for data loss. Same with `ToCharArray()`, which returns an array of `wchar_t` characters.  In both cases, you need to use `WideCharToMultiByte()` or `System::Text::Encoding::GetBytes()` or other similar data conversion routine to change 16bit unicode strings into 8bit ansi strings.

Comment: thanks I will check this out